# Question about Intersection Graph in Graph Theory

Tags: graph-theory, set-theory

I am reading "Intersection Graphs" from chapter 2 in Frank Harary Graph Theory Book

> Let $S$ be a set and $F=\{S_1,\ldots,S_p\}$ a nonempty family of distinct nonempty subsets of $S$ whose union is $S$. The intersection graph of $F$ is denoted $\Omega(F)$ and defined by $V(\Omega(F))=F$, with $S_i$ and $S_j$ adjacent whenever $i\neq j$ and $S_i\cap S_j\neq\emptyset$. Then a graph $G$ is an intersection graph on $S$ if there exists a family $F$ of subsets of $S$ for which $G$ and $\Omega(F)$ are isomorphic graphs.

Now, coming to my questions:

1. What is the set S in this context? Since we are talking about graphs is it "$S = ( V, E )$", where $V$ and $E$ themselves are sets?
2. Or is $S$ a set of all vertices and edges in a graph.

In either of the case, it does not make sense, cause the number of subsets, which I believe here mean a vertex in the resultant graph, would be more than the total vertex in the original graph and then the original and the resultant graph won't be isomorphic.

Comment: See [Graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_(discrete_mathematics)): "In mathematics, and more specifically in graph theory, a graph is a structure amounting to a set of objects in which some pairs of the objects are in some sense "related". The objects correspond to mathematical abstractions called vertices."

Comment: And see [Intersection graph](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_graph)

Comment: We have a *family* of sets $\{ S_1, \ldots, S_p \}$ and each $S_i$ is considered as a *vertex* $v_i$. Two sets $S_i,S_j$ having empty intersection are connected by an *edge*.

Comment: @PratikHadawale: Your questions are very hard to understand.
The last paragraph cannot be understood at all. 
To clarify the problem I note that there is a notion of abstract graph and there are examples of concrete graphs. The graph $\Omega$ is an example of a concrete graph that can be constructed for any set and almost any set of its subsets. An intersection graph is such an abstract graph that is isomorphic to some $\Omega$. Note that Harary proves that every graph is an intersection graph.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In general, the set $S$ can be anything you like, and the set $F$ can be any family of subsets of $S$ you like. There's no question of the "original graph" and "resultant graph" being isomorphic, because you're not necessarily starting with any "original graph": you are constructing a graph $\Omega(F)$ out of the information in $F$.

For example, suppose I am a big fan of the set family $\{\{1,2,3\}, \{2,3,4\}, \{3,4,5\}, \{4,5,6\}\}$. Then I could create the intersection graph $\Omega(\{\{1,2,3\}, \{2,3,4\}, \{3,4,5\}, \{4,5,6\}\})$, which would look like this:

[image]

Further, we say that a graph $G$ is an *intersection graph on $S$* if $G$ is isomorphic to $\Omega(F)$ for some $F$ that's a family of subsets of $S$. The diagram above shows that if you delete an edge from $K_4$ and call that $G$, then $G$ is an intersection graph on $\{1,2,3,4,5,6\}$.

When you're figuring out if we can represent a graph as an intersection graph, *then* we have a question of an "original graph" $G$ which we're comparing to $\Omega(F)$. But we're still not told what $S$ must be. We must pick $S$ and $F$ ourselves in some clever way that makes $\Omega(F)$ isomorphic to $G$.

For example, we can prove (and I think Harary does this) that every graph $G$ is an intersection graph on $E(G)$: the set of all edges in $G$. Specifically:

- Let $S = E(G)$;
- For every vertex $v \in V(G)$, let $S_v$ be the subset of all edges incident to $v$;
- Let $F = \{S_v : v \in V(G)\}$.

Then $\Omega(F)$ is isomorphic to $G$.

Some special families of graphs also have other representations as intersection graphs, with a different $S$ and $F$.

Comment: This makes it more clear

Comment: This makes it more clear, so the statement that I posted in blockquotes has two parts to it. First part just talks about "creating graphs out of a pure set and using set operation where the initial set S can be anything I like and F would be a clever collection of subsets of S that can result into graph upon intersection" while the second part talks about "comparing an actual graph G with a graph created using the first part but here too S is up to the person to choose, so here too we can choose S and  F but Harary does mention a clever way to use the graph  G itself  as a basis for creating S

Comment: Do i understand this  correctly? Also, Thank you so much it feels so great to understand a concept :)

Comment: Yep, that sounds right!

Comment: Hello, I have one more question for you, looks like you have read Harary's Graph Theory book. I am not great with maths, and I am using this book for an exam ( they specifically mentioned this book ) i am loving this book so far, but not gonna lie it's a bit concise while explaining theorems. I always end up with reddit, stackexchange, youtube or websites to find an explanation for mentione proof

Do you have any good resource, that I can use with Harary's Graph Theory book?

Please and Thank You!